# MAMP - Unable to turn off PHP E_STRICT error reporting

Tags: php5, mamp

For some reason, MAMP won't allow me to turn off E_STRICT warnings.  I've tried everything from changing the value explicitly in php.ini to error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT) in my file... to explicitly saying php_ini('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT).  I'm entirely confused as to why this is happening, and from what I can tell its specific to MAMP.

The version of *PHP* I'm running is 5.2.13 - and before you start telling me I shouldn't be ignoring those warnings, lets just be clear that I am using a framework that requires that E_STRICT be ignored.  (lame, I know.)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Tried adding in htaccess and event using error_reporting(); in index.php Nothing worked. @Mark37 please post the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try editing your php.ini (line 270)

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

If that fails, try it by editing the .htaccess file in the root-folder

```
php_value error_reporting 6143
```

If even that fails, look for the line 'display_errors = Off' and change it to:

```
display_errors = Off
```

Be careful, sometimes there is more then one occurrence.

Comment: E_STRICT isn't even listed as an option in php.ini, and setting the value manually just seems to ignore it.

Comment: Hmmm, Ok... Maybe MAMP changed something to it... Try the edit above.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are editing the correct php.ini using *phpinfo();*  ?

Comment: The *solution* really is editing the right .ini file, and phpinfo() was spot on!, I just edited the right ini and it solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are editing the correct php.ini by checking with phpinfo();
2. Make sure you restart apache to apply the new settings

... Only suggesting these since they are not explicitly stated in the question, but you've probably done both.

Comment: Although now I see that you tried php_ini function...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've found a solution for this.
I had exactly the same problem and this is how I've fixed it:

1) create a vhost in MAMP (not sure if necessary but this way it works)
2) inside the vhost config, you add this line:

```
php_admin_value error_reporting 6143
```

Notice its php_admin_value instead of php_value ? This changes everything!

3) restart MAMP and profit!